# How to use loc from pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have this code to replace ages from numeric data to categorical data. I'm trying to do it that way, but it's not working. Can anybody help me?

```
for df in treino_teste:
    df.loc[df['Age'] <= 13, 'Age'] = 0,
    df.loc[(df['Age'] > 13) & (df['Age'] <= 18), 'Age'] = 1,
    df.loc[(df['Age'] > 18) & (df['Age'] <= 25), 'Age'] = 2,
    df.loc[(df['Age'] > 25) & (df['Age'] <= 35), 'Age'] = 3,
    df.loc[(df['Age'] > 35) & (df['Age'] <= 60), 'Age'] = 4,
    df.loc[df['Age'] > 60, 'Age'] = 5
```

Error:

[image: Error image]

Comment: remove the trailing commas

Comment: also check out `pd.cut()` for something like this.

Comment: `df['Age'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], [0, 13, 18, 25, 35, 60,130], labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5])`,refer [pandas cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- there is capability for categorising continuous data
- for purpose of example I've assign the **bin** to a new column.  I could have assigned it back to **Age**
- for ease of reading results I have sorted, this is not needed

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Age":np.random.randint(1,65,10)}).sort_values(["Age"])

bins = [0,13,18,25,35,60,100]
df.assign(AgeB=pd.cut(df.Age, bins=bins, labels=[i for i,v in enumerate(bins[:-1])]))
```

|  | Age | AgeB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 12 | 0 |
| 3 | 13 | 0 |
| 8 | 18 | 1 |
| 7 | 25 | 2 |
| 9 | 25 | 2 |
| 1 | 27 | 3 |
| 2 | 30 | 3 |
| 4 | 57 | 4 |
| 0 | 59 | 4 |
| 6 | 64 | 5 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy.digitize()

```
bins = [0,13,18,25,35,60,100]
df['AgeC'] =numpy.digitize(df['Age'],bins)
```